# customize div of a year range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 2007,
            max: 2013,
            values: [ 2008, 2010 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val(  ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    });
    </script>
```

In the code above i had taken a div with id slider-range i am using slider function for sliding.When i slide a slider am calling the event for sliding and displaying the values from 2007 to 2013. But i need to add some text such as 2007 to 2013 inside a div.Once we add this text to a div when we slide a slider to this year i need to get that value is there anyways to add customized text inside the slider div.

Comment: You just want labels for the years you can slide to? This should be pretty easy, but I think I need more context with the way your HTML is marked up. Care to provide a [JS Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: what is needed http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2BxKV/1/

Comment: the above code will produce the same result but i need to customize the slider inside the slider i need to write the text such as 2008,2009